# Juypter notebook pandas_profiling: cannot import name 'to_html' from 'pandas_profiling.report'

Tags: python, pandas-profiling

I am trying to import pandas profiling.

```py
import pandas as pd
!pip install pandas_profiling
import pandas_profiling as pp
```

However, there is a error message saying that cannot import name `to_html` from `pandas_profiling.report`

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error using pip, but it worked like a charm after using the conda install

```
conda install -c conda-forge pandas-profiling
```

If you're not using Conda environment, i'd suggest install directly from the github using:

pip install https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling/archive/master.zip

Answer (score 0):

the above solution was not working in my case

use this on your anaconda prompt

```bash
conda env create -n pandas-profiling
conda activate pandas-profiling
conda install -c conda-forge pandas-profiling
```

then you can use profile report on your editor

```py
from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport
```

it will work for sure