# Cannot import name 'to_html' from 'pandas_profiling.report' using JupyterLab

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, pandas-profiling

I'm new using Jupyter Lab and Pandas profiling.

I'm trying to install and import and install Pandas Profiling in a jupyter notebook. I'm able to install pandas collab using pip, but unable to import the library. The error says I cannot import name 'to_html' from 'pandas_profiling.report'.

[Here's the code and the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TRZv.png)

Funny thing is: I also tried to run the notebook in Google Colab, but I got a different but similar error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'PandasProfiling' from 'pandas_profiling' (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas_profiling/__init__.py)
```

I already tried to use Jupyter Lab and Jupyter Notebook from Anaconda and Google Colab to see if it works, but no look.

Answer (score 0):

```
conda install -c conda-forge pandas-profiling
```

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60235171/juypter-notebook-pandas-profiling-cannot-import-name-to-html-from-pandas-pro).

Answer (score 0):

```
from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport
```

https://pandas-profiling.ydata.ai/docs/master/pages/getting_started/quickstart.html

PandasProfiling object does not exist.